# Net::HTTP::Get to RestClient.get

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I make a request and get a response with the following ruby script:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'

url = URI("https://somesite.com/api/advisors/2050212?api_key=some_key&username=some_username)

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request["cache-control"] = 'no-cache'
request["token"] = 'token'

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

Using [RestClient](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rest-client/rest-client) I build the following:

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new 'https://somesite.com/api/advisors', {params: {id: 2050212, api_key: 'some_key', username: 'some_username' }}
resource.get
```

I get this response:

```
RestClient::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:74:in `return!'
```

Dabbling in RestClient for the first time. How do I build the options hash?

Comment: This means you're being rejected since there's presumably some kind of access control mechanism blocking you. There's nothing necessarily wrong with your request.

Answer (score 0):

As @tadman said you set all options right.

You're getting 401 because you set `header["token"] = 'token'` with `Net::HTTP` but didn't do that with `RestClient`

I assume that approach will help.

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new 'https://somesite.com/api/advisors', {params: {id: 2050212, api_key: 'some_key', username: 'some_username' }}
resource.get({'token' => 'token'})
```

From [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/resource.rb#L49)